# Dynamical systems and manifolds

Tags: manifolds, dynamical-systems

I am trying to dip my toes into random dynamical systems. I am trying to understand the following:

Consider a process of iterates $$T_0 ^k = T_0 \circ \ldots ^k \ldots\circ T_0,\ \ \ \  k\geq 1$$
of a smooth transformation $T_0: M$ ⟲ of a manifold onto itself.

The first part seems understandable. Say, take $T_0  = f_0 (x) = x^2 + 3$, and then just iterate starting at some value.

Now, I do not have a strong background in topology or differential geometry. Hopefully this will change in the future. I know the very basics of the subjects at best. So, I am not really understanding what a manifold has to do with any of this, and I have never seen that "circle arrow" symbol before in my life.

Is there a way anyone can explain what is going on here without going to in depth about manifolds? Or is it completely useless to look at this stuff right now and just come back when I have a stronger pure math background?

Thanks.

Comment: I have never seen that circle arrow as well, but the words seem perfectly understandable. It is just saying $T_0:M\to M$ is a mapping of $M$ into $M$ and then $T_0^k$ is the $k$-fold composition. Maybe the circular arrow is just meant to emphasize the function is mapping the set into itself?

Comment: @peek-a-boo yes, that's the usual interpretation. I've seen it a lot in chalk talks and handwritten notes, never seen it typeset before though.

Comment: The manifold in your example is just $\mathbb{R}$, or whatever similarly one-dimensional continuous thing $x$ happens to be an element of. It might be easier to give an answer that will help you understand "what a manifold has to do with any of this" if you explain the context in which you encountered this notion of an iterated smooth transformation?

Comment: @SophieMacDonald Ok- this is definitely the answer I was looking for. Thanks! So, until I learn more about manifolds, for now I can assume it is just a generalization of $\mathbb{R} ^n?$ Basically just some smooth function with nice properties being composed with itself?

Comment: @MathIsLife12 yes, that's going to be the most helpful way to think about it for now. As the answer from John B indicates, you'll eventually need more than that, but cross that bridge when you come to it. Specifically, it's probably best to get familiar with a good, diverse range of concrete examples first, so that when it does become necessary to understand the formalism, you don't struggle as much to connect it to your interests.

Comment: I've seen $f: M\hookleftarrow$ used too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circle arrow is standard in the area: it avoids writing $M$ once more, as in $M\to M$. But I never understand why people want to avoid one extra character.

(Smooth) manifolds are the spaces where we can define smooth maps, although locally (meaning: up to a diffeomorphism) they are always like $\mathbb R^n$ for some $n$. The problem is that many interesting properties only occur because of nonlocal properties. For example, if the manifold is compact, which is not a local property, then some quite interesting dynamics starts to occur.

So, although you don't specify your interests, unavoidably you will need eventually to learn about smooth manifolds a bit more, but only as a user, which only requires the basics.